Ошибка "No file created in the directory" расширения TexMaths в LibreOffice
TexMaths нормально устанавливается, запускается, затем я устанавливаю пути для Tex'овских программ, но при попытке создать любое уравнение появляется ошибка. Кто знает как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста. Версия LibreOffice 7.6.5.2, версия TexMaths 0.52.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка. заголовок типа "пробема с тем-то" - плохой заголовок.
